# How would Conjured Animals work as mounts in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, summoning, mounted-combat

A previous question "[Can Conjure Animals beasts be used as mounts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94361/can-conjure-animals-beasts-be-used-as-mounts)" suggests that a Druid could use a summoned animal as a mount.  However, how might this work in combat?  Would the conjured animal act and be controlled like any other mount?

Furthermore, could a conjured animal act as a mount for another party member?  Per the spell (emphasis mine):

> **The summoned creatures are friendly to you and your companions.** Roll
>   initiative for the summoned creatures as a group, which has its own
>   turns. They obey any verbal commands that you issue to them (no action
>   required by you). If you don't issue any commands to them, they defend
>   themselves from hostile creatures, but otherwise take no actions.

Could the summoned animal be controlled as a mount by the other party member?  What if the druid commanded the conjured animal to obey the commands of the other party member, or ask as a mount?  Do summoned fey spirits act like the animals form they take?

Answer (score 1):

## Follow the Standard Mounted Combat Rules

Given the relevance of the linked question on Conjure Animal beasts as mounts, it continues seamlessly into this one: The conjured animals acting as mounts would continue to require following the same Mounted Combat rules found in the PHB.

To further answer your more specific questions:

**Could the summoned animal be controlled by the other party member?** Yes, just like any other animal. The summoned beasts are friendly to you and your party as quoted in your question.

**What if the druid commanded the conjured animal to obey the commands of the other party member?** See the first question, this is unnecessary as the beast is friendly to all party members and will work as a normal mount.

**Do summoned fey spirits act like the animals form they take?** They are the animal for all intents and purposes, they're stuff is just that of Fey.